# How to match & then replace multiple lines in shell script

Tags: shell, sed

Hi I have this text file.

```
Physical interface: ge-0/0/3, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Interface index: 132, SNMP ifIndex: 504
  Description: # SURVEILLANCE CAMERA #
  Link-level type: Flexible-Ethernet, Media type: Copper, MTU: 9000,
  LAN-PHY mode, Link-mode: Full-duplex, Speed: 1000mbps, BPDU Error: None,
   .....few more lines
Physical interface: ge-0/1/0, Enabled, Physical link is Down
  Interface index: 133, SNMP ifIndex: 505
  Link-level type: Ethernet, Media type: Fiber, MTU: 1514, LAN-PHY mode,
  Speed: 1000mbps, BPDU Error: None, MAC-REWRITE Error: None,
    .....few more lines
Physical interface: ge-0/1/3, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Interface index: 136, SNMP ifIndex: 508
  Description: # TO CSS_I-TN-CHNN-ENB-I099 #
  Link-level type: Flexible-Ethernet, Media type: Fiber, MTU: 8000,
  LAN-PHY mode, Speed: 1000mbps, BPDU Error: None, MAC-REWRITE Error: None,
   ... few more lines

 and so on....
```

Now If Physical link is Up  & value of MTU is 9000 then only I need to replace both the corresponding lines as.

```
<Pass>Physical interface: ge-0/0/3, Enabled, Physical link is Up
&
<Pass>Link-level type: Flexible-Ethernet, Media type: Fiber, MTU: 9000,
```

In every other situation it will be `<Fail>` in place of `<Pass>` . these values lie in different line that why I am not getting any idea of using sed or anything else..please help... here is the expected output..

```
 <Pass>Physical interface: ge-0/0/3, Enabled, Physical link is Up
      Interface index: 132, SNMP ifIndex: 504
      Description: # SURVEILLANCE CAMERA #
      <Pass>Link-level type: Flexible-Ethernet, Media type: Copper, MTU: 9000,
      LAN-PHY mode, Link-mode: Full-duplex, Speed: 1000mbps, BPDU Error: None,
         .....few more lines
  <Fail>Physical interface: ge-0/1/0, Enabled, Physical link is Down
     Interface index: 133, SNMP ifIndex: 505
     <Fail>Link-level type: Ethernet, Media type: Fiber, MTU: 1514, LAN-PHY mode,
     Speed: 1000mbps, BPDU Error: None, MAC-REWRITE Error: None,
            .....few more lines
   <Fail>Physical interface: ge-0/1/3, Enabled, Physical link is Up
     Interface index: 136, SNMP ifIndex: 508
     Description: # TO CSS_I-TN-CHNN-ENB-I099 #
     <Fail>Link-level type: Flexible-Ethernet, Media type: Fiber, MTU: 8000,
     LAN-PHY mode, Speed: 1000mbps, BPDU Error: None, MAC-REWRITE Error: None,
           ... few more lines

         and so on....
```

Comment: Did you already try something, maybe using `sed`? If yes, please, show us!

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have append the expected output in the original query..

Comment: @F.Hauri I was trying to find any option with sed which just searches the previous occurrence of "Physical link is Up" once it searches "MTU: 9000" & replaces both of them.. but didn't succeed..

Comment: what above awk? did you want the preserve the leading spaces?

Comment: Is there any separator between the "Physical interface" blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/Physical link is/ { :a /MTU:/! { N; ba; }; /Physical link is Up.*MTU: 9000/ { s/\(.*\n\)\s*/<Pass>\1<Pass>/; b; }; s/\(.*\n\)\s*/<Fail>\1<Fail>/; }' filename
```

That is:

```
/Physical link is/ {                       # Block start found
  :a
  /MTU:/! {                                # fetch lines until we find the MTU
    N
    ba
  }
  /Physical link is Up.*MTU: 9000/ {       # If link is up and MTU 9000
    s/\(.*\n\)[[:space:]]*/<Pass>\1<Pass>/ # insert Pass markers
    b
                                           # we're done.
  }
  s/\(.*\n\)[[:space:]]*/<Fail>\1<Fail>/   # otherwise insert Fail markers
}
```

Note that with BSD sed, this cannot be used as a one-liner because of the `b` instructions. In that case, put the expanded (without comments, for BSD sed is easily confused) code in a file, say `foo.sed`, and use `sed -f foo.sed filename`. I've already replaced the other GNU-ism (`\s`) with its POSIX equivalent (`[[:space:]]`) there.

To keep the whitespaces at the beginning of the MTU line, remove the `\s` or `[[:space:]]`. To place the whitespaces before the result marker, put the `\s` or `[[:space:]]` inside the capturing group (i.e., `\(.*\n\s*\)`).

**Also note:** This assumes that every interface description has an MTU field.

Alternatively, you might try this awk script:

```
awk -v RS='Physical interface:' -F '\n' -v OFS='\n' '{ result = "<Fail>" } /Physical link is Up/ && /MTU: 9000/ { result = "<Pass>" } NR != 1 { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { if(index($i, "MTU:")) { sub(/^ */, result, $i) } } print result RS $0 }' filename
```

This splits the file into records at `Physical interface:` and the records into fields at newlines. Then:

```
{ result = "<Fail>" }                  # result is Fail 
/Physical link is Up/ && /MTU: 9000/ { # unless link is up and MTU 9000
  result = "<Pass>"
}

NR != 1 {                              # the first record is the empty string
                                       # before the first actual record, so
                                       # we remove it.
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {           # wade through the fields (lines)
    if(index($i, "MTU:")) {            # find the MTU line
      sub(/^ */, result, $i)           # put the marker there. To keep the
                                       # whitespace, use $i = result $i
                                       # instead, or sub(/^ */, "&" result, $i)
                                       # to keep the spaces before the marker.
    }
  }
  print result RS $0                   # once done, print the whole shebang.
                                       # We have to reinsert the record
                                       # separator because it was removed
                                       # by the splitting.
}
```

Note that a multi-character `RS` is not strictly POSIX-conforming. The most common awks (gawk and mawk) support it, though. Notably, BSD awk does not.

Comment: Good stuff. The `sed` solution doesn't preserve the whitespace at the start of the `Link-level type` lines. Is there a way to fix that?
In the `awk` solution the way to preserve that whitespace is to use `sub(/^ */, "&" result, $i)` - `$i = result $i` won't work, because Awk rebuilds the line and thereby discards leading whitespace.

Comment: @mklement0 In the sed solution, just remove the `\s` or `[[:space:]]`, as I wrote there. The `$i = result $i` does, in fact, work because the leading whitespaces are not removed in field splitting if the field separator is a newline. OP's example output suggests that the whitespaces should be removed, though.

Comment: Sorry, missed the hint re removing `\s*` /  `[[:space:]]*`. However, that doesn't actually work, because it preserves the whitespace _after_ placing `<Pass>`/ `<Fail>` _at the very beginning_ of the line. Similarly, re Awk: Both our statements are correct in isolation (thanks for pointing out that `-F'\n'` does _not_ trim leading/trailing whitespace), but _neither applies to the situtation at hand_, given that you rebuild the line with `result` as the first token, which invariably replaces any leading whitespace. Thus, `sub(/^ */, "&" result, $i)` is the right solution here.

Comment: Re multi-character `RS` values: GNU Awk and Mawk support them, BSD Awk (as also used on OSX) does not.

Comment: Re BSD-Sed-compatible solution: BSD Sed is a finicky beast: (a) it won't support where you've placed your comments (in short: use whole-line comments only or terminate statements with `;` - the latter is not an option with labels and branching commands).
More importantly, (b) it doesn't support `\n` _inside a character class_, so the best you can do is to use `/Up.*MTU: 9000/` instead (leaving word-boundary issues aside).

Comment: Re _single-line_ BSD Sed solution: It probably gets messy, but you _do_ have 2 options: if you're using Bash, you can use an ANSI C-quoted string to create newlines with `$'\n'` where needed (if you use a _single_ `$'…'` string, be sure to double backslashes); alternatively, split your script into multiple `-e` options, with each part ending where BSD Sed requires an actual newline:
`sed -e '/Physical link is/ { :a' -e '/MTU:/! { N; ba' -e '}; /Up.*MTU: 9000/ { s/\(.*\n\)[[:space:]]*/<Pass>\1<Pass>/; b' -e '}; s/\(.*\n\)[[:space:]]*/<Fail>\1<Fail>/; }' filename`

Comment: Oh, that's where you want the spaces. I put in fixes for BSD sed and mentioned how to get the spaces that way; I really don't think that's what OP intends, though. Splitting with `-e` is not enough to make BSD sed accept the branch instructions, by the way (at least not on FreeBSD 9.1). The bash `$''` string should work.

Comment: Thanks for the update; the OP's expected output suggests that the fail/pass tag should go _after_ the leading whitespace, but now you have all cases covered. +

Comment: Re multiple `-e` options: curious: works on my OSX 10.10.2 system, and the following simple test also works for me on FreeBSD 10: `{ echo one; echo two; echo three; } | sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}; s/\n/@/g'` (reads all lines at once, then replaces interior newlines with `@`). Does it work for you?

Comment: Oh, interesting. Yes, it works with FreeBSD 9.1, and today I learned that it's not just the branch instructions that need to be split off this way but also the labels. I tried `sed -e ':a; $!{ N; ba' -e '}'` before and got complaints about an unexpected `}`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following `awk` command, which should be POSIX-compliant and preserves leading whitespace:

```
awk '
 / Physical link is / { ++count }
 /, MTU: / {
    tag = (blockLines[1] ~ /Up$/ && $0 ~ /, MTU: 9000,/ ? "<Pass>" : "<Fail>")
    sub(/^/, "&" tag, blockLines[1])
    sub(/^ +/, "&" tag)
    for (i = 1; i < count; ++i) print blockLines[i]
    count = 0
 }
 count > 0 { blockLines[count++] = $0; next }
 { print }
' file
```

The basic idea is:

- Collect a block of lines - all lines between and including the two lines that must be tagged - in an array without printing them yet.
- On reaching the end of the block, determine what tag (fail or pass) must be used
- Print all lines in the block, with the first and last one tagged accordingly.

*Annotated version* of the Awk script only:

```
 / Physical link is / { ++count } # Start of block
 /, MTU: / {                      # End of block - fail/pass can now be determined
    # Determine whether to apply a fail or a pass tag based on the
    # first and last line in the block.
    tag = (blockLines[1] ~ /Up$/ && $0 ~ /, MTU: 9000,/ ? "<Pass>" : "<Fail>")
    # Prepend tag to 1st line in block
    sub(/^/, "&" tag, blockLines[1])
    # Prepend tag to last line in block, preserving leading whitespace.
    sub(/^ +/, "&" tag)
    # Print all lines in block (except for last one).
    for (i = 1; i < count; ++i) print blockLines[i]
    # Reset block line counter.
    count = 0
 }
 # Inside block: collect lines, do not print yet.
 count > 0 { blockLines[count++] = $0; next }
 # Print last line in block and lines outside of blocks.
 { print }
```